# Major issues fitting new drain to bathroom sink

Tags: drain, sink

So I’m replacing a bathroom faucet. Faucet went on no problem. The drain however, is not going so smoothly. The previous drain was the metal popup kind. The new one is a Pfister push & kind (example [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0094BHCXE)).

Now, this drain comes with a rubber gasket that is supposed to sit in the sink bowl, under the flange. The manufacturer expressly says not to use plumbers putty.

The problem I’m having is with my sink! There are two issues:

1) The sink is uneven so the drain does sit flush; as I tighten the assembly underneath, the drain pulls to the right.

[image: Drain pic 1]

2) There isn’t a recess that accepts the rubber gasket AND the flange, so both sit above the bottom of the sink. It seems like there’s some kind of ring of epoxy or plastic where the rubber gasket would otherwise nestle into.

[image: Drain pic 3]

So, what are my options? Ditch the top/sink side rubber gasket and use silicone? Try to remove that interior ring of material and hope the gasket and flange will fit into it and sit lower in the sink bowl?

I’m at a loss!

Comment: Any specific reason for not using putty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WTF is right! So the uneven sink drain is caused by porcelain chunks? If so they can be smoothed or leveled with a stone bit chucked into a drill. I'm unsure why the drain manufacturer doesn't want putty used with the drain? Putty is a neutral and mild sealer with no abrasive nor corrosive properties. Unless they give a specific reason for not using it, I would suggest it is your only option to make the new drain work. Perhaps that is what the white ring in photo #2 is for; an attempt to smooth and level the uneven drain opening. If it is solid it's epoxy. I see clear silicone in the photos; this must have given someone a headache in the past .

Comment: Thanks for the reply! What looks like silicone is actually a plastic coating that coats the entire inside of that cavity (around the overflow outlet, etc). And yeah, the contour of sink itself, around the drain, is not symmetrical. I think putty is my only bet at this point! Thanks!